# Adding JavaScript when I already have an action in my form?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, action

I want to use JavaScript to check for empty fields and incorrect characters, but the problem is I can't add an action because the form action already points to a PHP file. The JavaScript works when I put it in the action area, but I can't get it to work without doing that, and I need the PHP to be the action unfortunately. Here's the HTML code:

```
<form action="http://127.0.0.1:5723/donate-now.php" method="post" name="donateNow" class="formMargin">
```

And here's the JavaScript.

```
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["donateNow"]["first"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("Name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: and don't use alerts!

Comment: value will not be null so that check is useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your form tag to be :

```
<form action="http://127.0.0.1:5723/donate-now.php" method="post" name="donateNow" class="formMargin" onsubmit="return validateForm();" >
```

Comment: Perfect, whoever you are. Thank you. I'll mark it as answered in 9 minutes. :)

Answer (score 0):

use onSubmit

```
<form action="something.php" onSubmit="return isFormValid()">
```

javascript

```
function isFormValid(){
//validate here

return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use onSubmit to call your validate form function:

```
<form action="http://127.0.0.1:5723/donate-now.php" method="post" name="donateNow" class="formMargin" onsubmit="validateForm()">
```

You should also modify validateForm() to return true if successful validation has occurred:

```
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["donateNow"]["first"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("Name must be filled out");
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

More information can be found here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsubmit.asp

> Execute a JavaScript when a form is submitted:

```
<form onsubmit="myFunction()">
  Enter name: <input type="text">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<form action="http://127.0.0.1:5723/donate-now.php" method="post" name="donateNow" class="formMargin" onSubmit="return validateForm()">`

Try using this

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [onSubmit](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onsubmit.asp) event attribute. This will trigger validation script before submit. Form will not be submited if validateForm() returns false.

```
 <form action="http://127.0.0.1:5723/donate-now.php" method="post" name="donateNow" class="formMargin" onSubmit="return validateForm()">
```